# Generate range filters from a list of ranges

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have a list of items and each of these items contain a range (ex:5000-10.000)

I would like to make some filters for these items (ex:5000-10.000).

Example data :

- 5000 - 10000
- 5000 - 15000
- 16000 - 26000
- 24000 - 60000
- 1000000 - 6000000

So these would be the ranges for 5 items I have in my db.

I would expect to have the following filters 5000 - 10000, 10000 - 15000 , 15000 - 16000 etc (this is my approach and doesn't work exactly as I want it to because if there are a lot of items there would be a lof of filters.)

Desired output would be around 4-5 filters (this is for this current data set, it is possible sometimes there is a single item on the page) that would work for all the items in the current page. The number of filters should be dynamic if possible.

Programing language for this is not really a problem, I think this is more of a math problem than a programing problem. This will probably be implemented in more than one programing language.

If possible I would love to see a javascript or php approach to this but if not please just explain the logic part.

PS. I only need to know how to generate these filters, the actual filtering part is not necessary.

If you have any questions or don't understand exactly what I am trying to achieve please feel free to ask.

EDIT :

The data is just a simple key value array, each item has an array with min-max values.

```
array(
    array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'10000'),
    array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'15000'),
    array('min'=>'14000','max'=>'15000'),
    array('min'=>'1200000','max'=>'5000000'),
    array('min'=>'500000','max'=>'800000'),
    array('min'=>'18000','max'=>'170000'),
)
```

Comment: You are saying that you have these ranges in your DB. Is this one column selection or they are in separate columns?

Comment: Honestly i have no idea how your data exactly looks and what you try to do. Could you clarify it further? For example with a DB schema and the exact expected output.

Comment: @V4KK4R just think of it as an arrays with 2 keys array(array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'10000'),array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'15000'))

Comment: so do you want something that given n number of items on the page generates  X number of filters to be able to filter all items into at least one group?

Comment: @Quince yeah exactly, the only thing that matters is that is would be a fair number of filters and once filter it would contain a fair number of items. It doesn't really have to be something really precise.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want filters to split up every X records? How about just using a for loop to get the filters?

```
$i = getLowestPossibleValueFromDB();
$max = getHighestPossibleValueFromDb();
$filterSize = 5000;

$filters = array();
for($i; $i <= $max; $i += $filterSize) {
    filters[] = array('from' => $i, 'to' => $i + $filterSize - 1);
}
```

You could also define you always want 5 filters by replacing `$filterSize` with `$filterSize = (int)(($max - $i) / 5);`

Comment: They should be generated from the ranges present not by incrementing a number. Dunno exactly if this is possible but that's what I would like.The problem here is that it is possible to have a item with the range 1.000.000 - 5.000.000

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understand your question correctly. You can try it in php like this:

```
$array = array(array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'10000'),array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'15000'),array('min'=>'5000','max'=>'35000'));

$no_of_filters = count($array);

$max_numbers = array();
$min_numbers = array();
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    $max_numbers[] = $arr['max'];
    $min_numbers[] = $arr['min'];
}
$max = max($max_numbers);
$min = min($min_numbers);

$step = ceil(($max - $min) / $no_of_filters);

$result = array();

while($min < $max){

    $max_step = $min + $step;

    if($max_step > $max)
        $max_step = $max;

    $result[] = array(
                    'min' => $min,
                    'max' => $max_step, 
            );
    $min = $max_step;

}



echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
      (
          [min] => 5000
          [max] => 10000
      )

   [1] => Array
      (
          [min] => 5000
          [max] => 15000
      )

   [2] => Array
      (
          [min] => 5000
          [max] => 35000
      )

 )

/****************************/
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [min] => 5000
          [max] => 12500
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [min] => 12500
          [max] => 20000
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [min] => 20000
          [max] => 27500
      )

  [3] => Array
      (
          [min] => 27500
          [max] => 35000
      )

  )
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to decide the number of filters automatically ? The problem is that what if a page only has 2 items.

Comment: Well there can be many ways to automatically decide about the no. of filters. It is just up to you how you want it to be calculated. For instance in the above example I am creating filters equal to the size of the input array.

Comment: I know there can be many ways, It doesn't really matter which way, any way is good as long as the number of filters is also dynamic to the dataset. The problem is that I need this to be just friendly for end users... having the number of filters equal to the number of items it not a good solution because they can be 20-30 items sometimes.

Comment: Well then the above example calculated the count of the dataset array and creates those many filters.

Comment: I noticed but I don't think this is a good solution for larger dataset.